# Install ubuntu on half drive with uefi and encryption gives me swap error

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, uefi, encryption

I am trying to install lUbuntu and I need to install it only on half of disk but with UEFI and with encryption.

As far as I need only half of disk used, I peek "Something else" in step where they ask for instalation type.
Then I have my empty drive there. I creating new partition table. Create 100M drive for UEFI, as "create EFI System Partition".
Then I create 12G drive for swap.
Then I create 150G drive for actual linux instalation. But I wat to make it encrypted, so I create 150G of "physical volume for encryption", enter my password and press "Ok". BUT, I got "Unsafe swap space detected":

```
 An unsafe swap space has been detected.

 This is a fatal error since sensitive data could be written out to
 disk unencrypted. This would allow someone with access to the disk to
 recover parts of the encryption key or passphrase.

 Please disable the swap space (e.g. by running swapoff) or configure
 an encrypted swap space and then run setup of encrypted volumes again.
 This program will now abort.
```

So far. First question - how do I will make separate drive for swap with same encryption? How I will work without swap?
Anyway, I have removed swap partition, run in console `sudo swapoff -a` and tryes again. This time I have only uefi partition, this 150G partition with encryption and a mapper for ext4 encrypted partition. 
Than I toot error that I have no root partition, so I select mount point as `/` for that encrypted drive. Then I goot error that `/boot` should be outside encrypted container, so I create another one 100M partition for boot. Second question: do I need separated partitions for UEFI and `/boot`? 
Anyway then I click next for precessing instalation and got warning:

```
You have not selected any partitions for use as swap space. Enabling swap space is recommended so that the system can make btter use of availabe physical memory and so that it behaves better when physical memory is sarce.
you may experience installation problems if you do not have enough physical memory.

If you do not go back to the partitioning menu and assign a swap partition, the installation will continue without swap space.
```

So far, the third question: if on previous step it ask ne for removing swap then **why** it says that i need swap? Anyway I press "Continue". Will it install?

---

upd: during instalation I got: `the attempt to mount a filesystem with type ext4 in Encrypted volume (sda_crypt) failed`. The linux. The best.